# Is there a python function for subsampling a large sample set to match the distribution of a variable in another sample

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 sample data sets (pandas dataframes):

- df_1 = 700 students
- df_2 = 200 stuents

Each of the dataframes have the same columns

- student_id
- height

I want to subset `df_1` so that it also has 200 students where they have the same height distribution as the students in `df_2`. I have the mean, std, min, median of the `df_2` students if I can use that in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not sure if I got you completely right, but let me suggests two steps.

**Subsampling**

To create random subsample from your dataset, you can use the following function which will return a new dataframe (deepcopy) from your initial df (it will not be mutated).

```py
seed = 42
np.random.seed(seed)

def subsample(df, size: int):
    assert 0 < size < len(data)
    subsample_indexes = np.random.randint(0, len(data), size)
    return df.iloc[subsample_indexes, :].copy()
```

**Same Distribution ?**

For this, I can suggest you that you can use the subsampling function above, make some iterations (e.g 50 subsamples) compare each subsample's distribution to distribution of `df2`, a pseudo-code would be like this,

```py
def compare_distributions(df, df_compare, n_subsample = 50):
    preserve_subsample = False
    n = 1
    while not preserve_subsample or n < n_subsample:
        df_sub = subsample(df, 200)
        # check if distributions is similar
        # here you may conduct a hypothesis test and/or
        # look at some statistics
        preserve_subsample = compare(df_sub, df_compare)
        n += 1
    if not preserve_subsample:
        # return empty df
        return pd.DataFrame()
    return df_sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could combine [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with [`df.sample()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html).

For example, use `pd.cut()` to get the bin edges that separate `df_2.height` into 20 bins of 10 students each. Then iterate over those bins and for each bin, use `df.sample()` to sample 10 students from the subset of `df_1` that falls within that height bin. If there are fewer than 10 students in any such bin, you might consider sampling with replacement, or reducing the number of bins from the start.

This will give you a random subset of `df_1` with approximately the same height distribution as in `df_2`.